# Turn off composer install command when deploy on Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: php, linux, laravel, digital-ocean

I would like to ask if there is a way to disable the **composer install command** for my application on the Digital Ocean App Platform?

Btw I used [Digital Ocean App Platform](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/)

Here I want to ask about time to deploy the code is very long for code changes that are even only one line. This is because the server always runs `composer install` for **every** code deployment from github to the Digital Ocean server.

How do I turn off the composer install command in this case? I can run artisan commands through the console without having to repeat myself as I explained above

Please help